# How to select indices according to another tensor in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, indices

The task seems to be simple, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

So what I have are two tensors:

- an indices tensor `indices` with shape `(2, 5, 2)`, where the last dimensions corresponds to indices in x and y dimension
- a "value tensor" `value` with shape `(2, 5, 2, 16, 16)`, where I want the last two dimensions to be selected with x and y indices

To be more concrete, the indices are between 0 and 15 and I want to get an output:

```
out = value[:, :, :, x_indices, y_indices]
```

The shape of the output should therefore be of `(2, 5, 2)`. Can anybody help me here? Thanks a lot!

Edit:

I tried the suggestion with gather, but unfortunately it does not seem to work (I changed the dimensions, but it doesn't matter):

First I generate a coordinate grid:

```
y_t = torch.linspace(-1., 1., 16, device='cpu').reshape(16, 1).repeat(1, 16).unsqueeze(-1)
x_t = torch.linspace(-1., 1., 16, device='cpu').reshape(1, 16).repeat(16, 1).unsqueeze(-1)
grid = torch.cat((y_t, x_t), dim=-1).permute(2, 0, 1).unsqueeze(0)
grid = grid.unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, 3, 1, 1, 1)
```

In the next step, I am creating some indices. In this case, I always take index 1:

```
indices = torch.ones([1, 3, 2], dtype=torch.int64)
```

Next, I am using your method:

```
indices = indices.unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1)
new_coords = torch.gather(grid, -1, indices).squeeze(-1).squeeze(-1)
```

Finally, I manually select index 1 for x and y coordinate:

```
new_coords_manual = grid[:, :, :, 1, 1]
```

This outputs the following new coordinates:

```
new_coords
tensor([[[-1.0000, -0.8667],
         [-1.0000, -0.8667],
         [-1.0000, -0.8667]]])

new_coords_manual
tensor([[[-0.8667, -0.8667],
         [-0.8667, -0.8667],
         [-0.8667, -0.8667]]])
```

As you can see, it only works for one dimension. Do you have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: Could you show a minimal example `indices` and `value` and the desired output?

Comment: The desired output is achieved when producing `new_coords_manual`

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is flatten the first three axes together and apply [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html):

```
>>> grid.flatten(start_dim=0, end_dim=2).shape
torch.Size([6, 16, 16])

>>> torch.gather(grid.flatten(0, 2), axis=1, indices)
tensor([[[-0.8667, -0.8667],
         [-0.8667, -0.8667],
         [-0.8667, -0.8667]]])
```

As explained on the documentation page, this will perform:

> `out[i][j][k] = input[i][index[i][j][k]][k]  # if dim == 1`

Comment: Thanks for your help! This indeed works for batch size of 1, but it seems to face the same problems with batch size of > 1 :/ I also tried to split the problem in x and y coordinate and apply `indices_y = indices[:, :, 0].unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1)` followed by `new_y = torch.gather(grid, 3, indices_y).squeeze(-1).squeeze(-1)`. After doing the same with the x values and gather on dim=4 I concatenated the tensors. But I receive exactly the result from your first suggestion.

Comment: Why flatten first?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, thanks again @Ivan for your help! :)

The problem was, that i unsqueezed on the last dimension, while I should have unsqueezed in the middle dimensions, so that the indices are at the end:

```
y_t = torch.linspace(-1., 1., 16, device='cpu').reshape(16, 1).repeat(1, 16).unsqueeze(-1)
x_t = torch.linspace(-1., 1., 16, device='cpu').reshape(1, 16).repeat(16, 1).unsqueeze(-1)
grid = torch.cat((y_t, x_t), dim=-1).permute(2, 0, 1).unsqueeze(0)
grid = grid.unsqueeze(1).repeat(2, 3, 1, 1, 1)

indices = torch.ones([2, 3, 2], dtype=torch.int64).unsqueeze(-2).unsqueeze(-2)
new_coords = torch.gather(grid, 3, indices).squeeze(-2).squeeze(-2)

new_coords_manual = grid[:, :, :, 1, 1]
```

Now `new_coords` equals `new_coords_manual`.